# Problem adding add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

Tags: open-source-gis, ubuntugis, apt-get

Since upgrading my Ubuntu to focal (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) I get the following error every time that I update/upgrade my system:

```
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Is there now a different PPA that I should be using for my GIS updates?  Alternatively, is there another way that I can automate GIS updates?

Comment: [ubuntugis](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) doesn't have focal (20.04) packages, try [ubuntugis-unstable](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable).

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to have worked.  Will ubuntugis eventually have focal packages?  I generally try to avoid unstable packages.  But I need to keep my gis stuff up to date.

Comment: I presume so, but couldn't say. I've stopped using ubuntugis. If you're only after QGIS, I prefer the [QGIS respository](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). `ubuntugis-unstable` doesn't have unstable *packages*, it's the *repository* that's unstable - because they keep it updated with the latest releases.

Comment: OK.  I think that I understand.  Thanks for the explanation and help.